# Rsync problem copying folder to server (missing public-key)?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, command-line, files, rsync

I am a not very experienced with syncing or SSH.. but I am trying to sync a folder on my local linux machine to a remote webserver (local and remote running ubuntu).
When
I try this on my local machine:

```
sudo rsync -ahvz --progress /localshare/ myname@xxx:/var/www/html/upload/
```

I get this the first time:

```
The authenticity of host 'x.x.x.x' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:BkWg7o5BlblILzWh4d1hIcg0OsWCOu/04wkLM45XuS8.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? y
```

after that I tried the first command again:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

So I ran ssh-keygen on local machine

```
ssh-keygen -t -rsa -C "mymailadress@com" -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa -P ""
```

and generated  the public/private rsa key pair in the appropriate folders...

Now what? I have full access to the remote server (running apache)

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy the content of `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the server:

```
mkdir ~/.ssh && chmod 700 ~/.ssh
vim ~/.ssh/authorized_keys # edit file and paste your public key
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: or just `ssh-copy-id`

Comment: either recommondations does not seem to work still same error: 'Permission denied (publickey).'